# Why is list.add() adding items to object AND source object as well?

Tags: vb.net, list, addition

Hopefully this is simple enough. I need to be able to add elements to a copy of mylist.testlist without modifying the global mylist object. (Which seems to be happening via the below code.)

When I am working on x, which should be a totally separate object, mylist is getting modified as well. How can I fix this? I have worked with lists extensively and never seen this behavior before. I have tested and reproduced the problem in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 on Win 7 Pro 32bit.

TIA!

Source Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public mylist As New test

    Sub Main()
        Dim x As test = mylist
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            x.testlist.Add(False)
        Next

        MsgBox("x count: " + x.testlist.Count.ToString + vbCrLf + "mylist count: " + mylist.testlist.Count.ToString)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Main()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class test
    Public testlist As New List(Of Boolean)
    Public Sub New()
        testlist.Add(False)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why should `x` be a totally separate object than `mylist`? With `Dim x As test = mylist` you are referencing the same object.

Comment: I thought Dim x As test = mylist created a seperate object that was a copy of mylist. No? As well this is prototype code that I am using to solve this issue. The only purpose of this code is to demonstrate the problem I am having/perceiving.

Comment: As well I need to be able to create a copy of mylist so I can modify a copy of the mylist.testlist data without modifying the global mylist.testlist.

Comment: So are you saying `Dim x As test = mylist` is making `x` a pointer reference of some type to `mylist`? If so how do I avoid that behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tim Schmelter pointed out in his comment, your problem is the line:

```
Dim x As test = mylist
```

by which `x` gets a reference to `mylist`. That means **both** (`x` and `mylist`) are pointing to the same instance of `test`. That's why changing one of them is changing the other too.

To fix it, you could define `x` as a new instance of `test` and copy all elements from `mylist.testlist` to `x.testlist`.

Comment: Oye, I was afraid of that... Thanks for the insight! Appreciate the time! Is there any compile option I can change to avoid this?

Comment: No, this is standard and normal behavior. Seems like you are missing some basics. Can't give you a good reference to read up on this.

Comment: Alright, it is entirely possible I am just stumbling on this. I normally don't code this way but someone else brought the issue up and it just seemed a little odd. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the link, Kirk.